# Создание квадратного View через xml

Tags: android, xml, view

Знаете те ли вы способ создать квадратное (высота = ширине) view через файл xml разметки (именно через **xml**, через КОД НЕ НАДО).

**Есть три ImageView растянуты на всю ширину экрана. есть ли способ сделать их квадратными через 
xml разметку?** что указать в качестве высоты, что бы они были квадратные или друго способ?

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   //???
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" //???
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" //???
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //???
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798392/imageview-have-height-match-width

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как-то так должно сработать

```
<androidx.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" />

</androidx.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: заменить LinearLayout на ConstraintLayout и выставить там app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"?

Comment: может имеет смыл в тексте ответа изменить `View` на  `ImageView` ?

Comment: это не важно, в контексте вопроса View даже лучше (ImageView я привел в качестве примера)

Comment: окей, я понял :)

Comment: Да это сработало для меня при условии android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: @igo потому что когда вы ставите 0 - лайаут начинает считать эту размерность только из зависимостей. Если будет wrap_content или конкретное значение, то они перебьют правило "соотношение сторон 1 к 1"