# Как задать ширину через высоту?

Tags: android, android-layout

Условно у меня есть объект, в котором ширина стоит match parent, и я хочу чтобы высота была width/2, или  что-то подобное, как такое можно сделать?

Comment: В заголовке ширина через высоту, в вопросе наоборот.

Comment: Безразницы, мне важно, как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

строка *app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"* задает ширину в две высоты

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1" />
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089399/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-view-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-xml

Comment: А можно ли то же самое сделать с разными объектами, тоесть, например, ширина textview = 2 ширины imageview?

Comment: @Lms наверняка можно что нибудь придумать, задавите вопрос...