# Как задать ширину объекта через ширину другого объекта?

Tags: android, xml, height, width

У меня есть textview, и мне нужно, что бы его ширина была равна условно 2 ширины imageview, или любого другого объекта. Можно ли задать параметр объекта через параметры другого объекта и как?

Нужно именно решение в разметке, в коде не надо.

Comment: Это очень сложная и общая задача. Простого решения нет, однако можно написать своё правило для ConstraintLayout, которое будет делать то, что вам нужно. Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/3212712

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать ширину через высоту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099361/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: @Style-7 нет, так как там я спрашивал про изменения в рамках одного объекта, а тут с разными